# Crystal Reports 2008/2011 integration with Delphi XE

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, crystal-reports-2008

Help me please, I need to run Crystal Reports (.rpt) file and see the Preview output from my Delphi XE application on the client computers where CR is not installed. I found the way to do it with CR XI, but it does not work with CR 2008.

Comment: Apparently the ActiveX thing works for some people, but it's deprecated by BusinessObjects/SAP and is going to be retired completely, soon, as it doesn't function right any more.

Answer (score 3):

I talked to SAP support about this recently.  The latest Crystal Reports only supports Java and .Net.

The last version that had Delphi support was CR XI, and it only supported Delphi 7.  This was a binary solution, that couldn't be ported to more recent versions of Delphi.  As discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3911912/delphi-xe-calling-crystal-reports), there is apparently a patch that allows you to use CR XI in Delphi 2009 and (with varying degrees of success) Delphi 2010 and XE.

As far as I know, there is no solution to use more recent versions of Crystal Reports with Delphi or any native development tool.

Comment: +1 Because this is the sad truth... Worth trying some OpenSource solutions for future projects. And AFAIK even the CR XI version is not easily compatible with Windows Server 2008 64 bit - [perhaps a workaround available here](http://sjc.ironspeed.com/post?id=3728528). :(

Comment: related question that seems to give hope, but which in the end, is a false end: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/378089/how-can-i-display-crystal-xi-reports-inside-a-delphi-2007-application?rq=1