# Parameter with wrong size

Tags: delphi, crystal-reports

We have a system in Delphi 2007 and we use the `TCrpe` component to print reports made in Crystal Reports 2008 (`.rpt` files). Works normally as follows in the code below:

```
vImpressora := '\\DEV-01\HP LaserJet Professional P1102w';
with DM.Crystal do begin
  CloseEngine;
  ReportName := 'Comprovante.rpt';
  ParamFields.Items[0].CurrentValue := 'Empresa XYZ Ltda';
  Printer.Name := vImpressora;
  Print;
end;
```

But now we need to convert the system to Delphi 10. In the above code, `CurrentValue` simply stopped working. When the system runs the command `ParamFields.Items[0].CurrentValue := 'XYZ Company All';` an error is generated:

> Parameter has invalid structure size

I've looked through several sites/forums for a solution to the problem, but couldn't find it. It makes no sense. The parameter within the report is a type parameter that prints the report title and logically is of type String.

Comment: Between Delphi 2007 and 2009, the string-handling was radically changed, from defaulting to Ascii to defaulting to Unicode.  So, I think you probably need to update your TCrpe component to match whichever new version of Delphi you are using.  Btw, there is no Delphi 10 as such:  which exact version of Delphi are you trying to upgrade to?

Comment: You may find the second answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3911912/delphi-xe-calling-crystal-reports) helpful asTCrpe now appears to be not being maintained.

Comment: @MartynA. The link you provided is really helpful. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify all the source of TCPRE by changing the String to AnsiString

Comment: Be aware that TCrpe is a proprietary component, which means you don't have the right to modify it.

Comment: @Rui Filipe Ribeiro. Thank you Rui for your suggestion. It saved my day.

Comment: @Olivier. Thank you Olivier, indeed you are right. I will consider that too !